# DevExpress XAF WinApplication.UseOldTemplates Difference

Tags: devexpress, xaf

What is the difference between `UseOldTemplates = true;` and `UseOldTemplates = false;`?
(Devexpress XAF).

I am  asking because there is a handy [controller](https://github.com/expand/eXpand/blob/da579a97960e6559efc253e5e022218ca091f7c2/Xpand/Xpand.ExpressApp/Xpand.ExpressApp.Win/SystemModule/RibbonFromModelController.cs) that uses old templates.

Answer (score 0):

From the DevExpress [XAF blog](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/eaf/archive/2014/11/18/xaf-brand-new-module-amp-features-for-both-windows-and-the-web-coming-soon-in-v14-2.aspx#ribbon-templates)

> We introduced the new Ribbon templates for Main and Detail forms of a
>   WinForms application. Now you can easily customize the placement of
>   your UI commands via the familiar interface of the RibbonControl
>   wizard you often see in traditional WinForms development:

In order to customize your Action controls there is a detailed document @ [How to: Customize Action Controls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113183/Task-Based-Help/Actions/How-to-Customize-Action-Controls)

Comment: Can the ribbonfrommodelcontroller be transformed to use new template

Comment: It might be possible but DevExpress is using a different more appropriate way to design templates and customize Actions Controls as in the doc I posted before

Comment: Thank you.Checked out the doc